# how to pass a custom form to django.contrib.auth.views.login

Tags: django, forms, authentication

I am trying to pass a custom template and form to auth.views.login. I am getting the error message. What is wrong with this?

in views.py,

```
def login_user(request, template_name='login.html', 
           redirect_field_name = None, 
           authentication_form = BootstrapAuthenticationForm,
           extra_context=None):
response = auth.views.login(request, template_name, redirect_field_name, authentication_form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **return** the response from your view:

```
def login_user(request, template_name='login.html', 
           redirect_field_name = None, 
           authentication_form = BootstrapAuthenticationForm,
           extra_context=None):
    return auth.views.login(request, template_name, redirect_field_name,
                            authentication_form)
```

Comment: Yes, at the end I have 'return response', so this is okay, but I am getting an error:  'module' object has no attribute 'views' at the login.

Comment: How do you import the `auth` module?